# Flask, Axios POST returns a Network error

Tags: vue.js, flask, axios

I'm trying to get my flask api working but still have some "network error" when I'm submitting my axios form in POST.

Thought it was a CORS error but I think I've done everything I could to get it to work. If anyone has an idea.

> API

```
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

    UPLOAD_FOLDER = './WorkingDirectory/'
    ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['mp3', 'wav'])

    app = Flask(__name__)
    cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})

    @app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    @cross_origin()
```

My axios post :

```
    onSubmit () {
        this.axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/',
        data: {
            file: this.form.file,
            reverb: 'reverb',
        },
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=utf-8',
        },
    }).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

> Exact error :

```
Login:  Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js?2d83:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js?b50d:87)
```

Comment: can you add the exact error

Comment: @mmenschig added it

Comment: The error message cited in the question is unrelated to CORS

Comment: Is your Flask service actually running? On port 5000?

Comment: @Phil My flask is running on port 5000 yes, weird issue, it seems (from what I see in my Chrome, is that it's sending a get). It works perfectly with postman and swagger tho.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call post from the axios and placing {} around data and headers.

```
     onSubmit () {
        const var path = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/'
        this.axios.post({
        path,
        {data: {
            file: this.form.file,
            reverb: 'reverb'
        }},
        {headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=utf-8'
        }},
    }).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```